# Pressed in buttons using CSS3 animation

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to make a bevel looking button as pressed in on active state. I want the transition to be smooth enough but the problem is I don't know how to bring that smoothness. What I have achieved is the following.

```css
.button {
  background-color: #ff962c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4), inset -2px -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);

}
.button:active {
  border: 1px solid #ff962c;
  background-color: #ffa346;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8), inset -1px -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #ffa346;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="" id="upload" class="button">
  <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-lg fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>

<a href="" id="view" class="button">
  <i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Take a look at css transitions! You can find a lot of tutorials on the internet, here's a basic one: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add css transitions. To be exact: `transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;`. I recommend changing only specific properties with transitions, especially if we are talking about box-shadows and other such heavy effects.

```css
.button {
  background-color: #ff962c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4), inset -2px -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
}
.button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8), inset -1px -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #ffa346;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="" id="upload" class="button">
  <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-lg fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>

<a href="" id="view" class="button">
  <i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Yes. Just one more thing, Is the colour scheme perfect to give it a pressed look with a bg #222D33?

Comment: @Ayan for these kind of questions i suggest you this site: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ayan you can just add 'background-color: #222D33;' to you .button':active' class, and make the transition on the button class 'transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out;' instead of 'transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;'. Note that by transitioning 'all .2s ease-in-out' you may transition properties that you do not intend to, and will definitely hinder the end-user experience by slowing down the performance of your website.

Comment: @VladOvaho, I meant bg colour of the page body not the element. :)

Comment: @MattiaNocerino, thanks for the pointer. Next time I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Ayan just to be clear: i didn't mean the original question, but the question that popped out in the comments! The main post totally fits here

Comment: @MattiaNocerino, I understood that and relevantly I answered you for the question that "popped out" and hence while asking the second question I said "Just one more thing". :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this, simply using `transitions`?
Have a look at this link too, it might be useful: [hover.css](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/)

```css
.button {
  background-color: #ff962c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4), inset -2px -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .1s ease;
  -o-transition: all .1s ease;
  transition: all .1s ease;
}
.button:active {
  border: 1px solid #ff962c;
  background-color: #ffa346;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8), inset -1px -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #ffa346;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="" id="upload" class="button">
  <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-lg fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>

<a href="" id="view" class="button">
  <i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```css
.button {
  background-color: #ff962c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4), inset -2px -2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  
}
.button:active {
  border: 1px solid #ff962c;
  background-color: #ffa346;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8), inset -1px -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .1s ease;
  -o-transition: all .1s ease;
  transition: all .1s ease;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #ffa346;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#" id="upload" class="button">
  <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-lg fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>

<a href="#" id="view" class="button">
  <i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg fa-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```